# Glide overlays screen with loaded image parts

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

Since i could not find anything related in the internet, this is gonna be my first SO question:

**Problem Description**

I am experiencing the following issue:
In my app i have a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager` which is displaying images loaded by Glide.

When scrolling slowly everything will work alright.

After scrolling fast up and down (to an extend one could arguably call it "abuse of scrolling") some image parts or whole images will randomly overlay my screen, so that the content below is no longer visible. This is especially the case on the edges of the screen.

The testing device where the described error occurs is a OnePlus One running CM12.1.1 (Android 5.1.1). I didn't test on other devices.

Any hints / help / explanation on why this is happening or how to fix it are appreciated.

### CODE

Below is the code for the Adapter with an inner ViewHolder class:

```java
public class PhotoListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotoListAdapter.PhotoHolder>{

  private ArrayList<PhotoDetail> mPhotos;
  private String mAccessToken;
  private int mUserId;
  private int mPageCounter = 1;
  private boolean mIsLoading = false;
  private boolean mEndReached = false;


  public PhotoListAdapter (String accessToken, int userId){
    mPhotos = new ArrayList<>();
    mAccessToken = accessToken;
    mUserId = userId;
    fetchPhotos();
  }

  @Override
  public PhotoHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo_list_item, parent, false);
      PhotoHolder photoHolder = new PhotoHolder(itemView);
      return photoHolder;
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(PhotoHolder holder, int position) {
      holder.bind(mPhotos.get(position));
      if (position == mPhotos.size() - 6) fetchPhotos();
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
      return mPhotos.size();
  }

  public void fetchPhotos () {
      if (mIsLoading || mEndReached) return;
      else {
          mIsLoading = true;
          //Retrofit call which will return a JSON Object with the Photo Details, like the filename
          // With this information i can build the URL of the image
          ApiProvider.getInstance().getApi().getPhotos(mUserId, mAccessToken, "time", "all", mPageCounter, mUserId, 32).enqueue(new Callback<PhotoResponseWrapper>() {
              @Override
              public void onResponse(Call<PhotoResponseWrapper> call, Response<PhotoResponseWrapper> response) {
                  if (response.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                      int photoCount = response.body().getPhotoResponse().getPhotosCount();
                      if (photoCount != 32) mEndReached = true;
                      Collections.addAll(mPhotos, response.body().getPhotoResponse().getPhotos());
                      notifyItemRangeInserted(mPhotos.size() - photoCount,photoCount);
                      mPageCounter++;
                  }
                  mIsLoading = false;
              }

              @Override
              public void onFailure(Call<PhotoResponseWrapper> call, Throwable t) {
                  mIsLoading = false;
              }
          });
      }
  }

  class PhotoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

      private ImageView mPhotoView;
      private PhotoDetail mPhotoDetail;

      public PhotoHolder(View itemView) {
          super(itemView);
          mPhotoView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_photo);
          mPhotoView.setOnClickListener(this);
      }

      public void bind (PhotoDetail photoDetail){
          mPhotoDetail = photoDetail;

          String photoUrl = Api.Endpoints.PHOTOS_SMALL + photoDetail.getUserId() + '/' + photoDetail.getFileName();
          mPhotoView.setContentDescription(photoDetail.getDescription());
          // First stop all pending image loads
          Glide.clear(mPhotoView);
          // Then load new url
          Glide.with(mPhotoView.getContext())
                  .load(photoUrl)
                  .into(mPhotoView);
      }

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

      }
  }
}
```

Below is the XML of a single Item:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/img_photo"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="@dimen/height_photo_item"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_photo_item"
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

Below is the XML of the RecyclerView:

```xml
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/layout_swipe_refresh"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_photo_item"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_photo_item"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_photo_item"
  tools:context=".fragments.PhotoListFragment">
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

### EXAMPLES

Some visual examples of the bug are these screenshots:

[image: Glide Bug]
[image: Glide Bug]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find any information on how to fix this, i tried out the major alternative image loading & caching library - [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso).
With this library the bug mentioned above wasn't reproducible for me, so i guess it is really Glide specific.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use placeholder image.

```
Glide.with(mPhotoView.getContext())
.load(photoUrl)
.placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder) // Your placeholder image
.into(mPhotoView);
```

I had the same problem and setting the placeholder eliminated it for me.